# number format exception - For input string: "35,9"

Tags: java, numberformatexception

I need to generate random values and print them.

But it throws an Exception:

```
 java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "35,9"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1241)
    at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
    at com.epam.lab.model.sweets.SweetsGenerator.paramFormatter(SweetsGenerator.java:71)
    at com.epam.lab.model.sweets.SweetsGenerator.next(SweetsGenerator.java:55)
    at com.epam.lab.model.NewYearGift.generate(NewYearGift.java:40)
    at com.epam.lab.controller.GiftController.generateGift(GiftController.java:86)
    at com.epam.lab.controller.GiftController.showGiftContent(GiftController.java:213)
    at com.epam.lab.view.Application.process(Application.java:89)
    at com.epam.lab.view.Application.estimateUserInput(Application.java:49)
    at com.epam.lab.view.Application.start(Application.java:43)
    at com.epam.lab.view.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

It happens only here:

```
public Sweets next() {      
    Sweets current = instances[rand.nextInt(instances.length)];
    double sugarParam = paramFormatter(randomSugarLevel(), PRECISION);
    double weightParam = paramFormatter(randomWeight(), PRECISION);

    try {
        return (Sweets) current.getClass()
                .getConstructor(double.class, double.class)
                .newInstance(sugarParam, weightParam);
        // Report programmer errors at run time:
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOG.error("RuntimeException", e);
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}


private double paramFormatter(double sugarParam, DecimalFormat df) {
    return Double.parseDouble(df.format(sugarParam));
}


private double randomWeight() {
    return WEIGHT_MIN + (Math.random() * ((WEIGHT_MAX - WEIGHT_MIN) + 1));
}


private double randomSugarLevel() {
    return SUGAR_MIN + (Math.random() * ((SUGAR_MAX - SUGAR_MIN) + 1));
}
```

And precision is constant:

> private static final DecimalFormat PRECISION = new DecimalFormat("#.#");

But all looks ok.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: try with dot instead of comma  39.9 instead of 39,5

Comment: your format pattern should be "#,#"

Comment: @Matheus: really? :) The pattern character "comma" represents the grouping separator while the OP is really using it as a decimal separator. Instead, the locale should be altered to one where a comma is being used as decimal separator.

Comment: Do you want to use a decimal separator of `,` instead of `.`, or did you mean to have `35.9` (with a `.`) as your input? Due to locale differences in usage of `.` or `,` as the decimal separator, there is confusion as to what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau: Matheus is talking about the pattern not the actual character :)

Comment: @BalusC Sorry, misread your first comment :)

Comment: Why are your formatting a `double` just to parse it?? Sounds like using `BigDecimal` to round would be a lot better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The input string contains `,` instead of `.`. Replace the `,` with `.` to get rid of the exception. Ideally, the input should be `35.9` and not `35,9`.

If you are using `,` as the decimal separator, then you could use the `DecimalFormatSymbols` to replace `,` as the decimal separator.

The following code demonstrates the use of `DecimalFormatSymbols` class:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
dfs.setDecimalSeparator(',');
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);
System.out.println(df.parse("35,9"));
```

The above code prints `35.9`

Comment: No, it should not be different that what it is. The problem is the `Locale` used for the `DecimalFormat`. Not everywhere in the world does a dot separate the decimals. His format could also be different.

Comment: @RahulBobhate all ok but should be `dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');` instead your solution.

Comment: @nazar_art, The default symbol for decimal separator is `.`, so we don't need to set it explicitly. However, in your case, you are receiving input which uses the decimal separator as `,` and not `.`, so you would need to set it explicitly **OR** you are using a `Locale` which uses `,` as the default decimal separator, in which case you are right.

Comment: @RahulBobhate I wrote project at another PC and now deployed to this one.

Comment: @RahulBobhate The default symbol depends on the `Locale` of the system on which the `DecimalFormat` is created unless specified in the constructor or afterward, or explicitly set by the application in which the `DecimalFormat` is created... it is not set in stone.